# Getter and Setter c#

Tags: c#

I have multiple objects(nodes) and each node has a getter and setter for a list named Calea which contains other nodes, also each node has neighbours and they are also nodes . The problem is that list is stacking up and I can't figure out why , it's like a static variable and also I am not using that getter and setter anywhere else.
Here is my code :

```
 private int cost = 10000;
 private LinkedList<GraphNode<string>> calea=new LinkedList<GraphNode<string>>() ;
 public int Cost
        {
            get
            {
                return cost;
            }
            set
            {
                cost = value;
            }
        }
         public LinkedList<GraphNode<string>> Calea
        {
            get
            {

                if (calea == null) return new LinkedList<GraphNode<string>>();

                return calea;

            }

            set
            {
              calea = value;

            }
        }
```

Code above shows the method for Cost and Calea , Cost works fine but Calea is stacking up.The code below is a sample of code of how I am setting the value Calea for each node:

```
if (curr.Neighbors.ElementAt(i).Cost > curr.Costs.ElementAt(i) + curr.Cost)
                {

                    curr.Neighbors.ElementAt(i).Cost = curr.Costs.ElementAt(i) + curr.Cost;

                    curr.Neighbors.ElementAt(i).Calea = curr.Calea;
                    curr.Neighbors.ElementAt(i).Calea.AddLast((GraphNode<string>)curr.Neighbors.ElementAt(i));

                    index = i;


                }  
                ++i;
```

The sample code where I change the current node below:

```
pathNodesToVisit.Remove(curr);
            if (pathNodesToVisit.Count == 0) break;
            if (curr.Neighbors.Count > index)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < pathNodesToVisit.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (pathNodesToVisit.ElementAt(j).Value == curr.Neighbors.ElementAt(index).Value)
                    {
                        indexx = j;
                        //MessageBox.Show(pathNodesToVisit.ElementAt(j).Value);
                    }
                }
                curr = pathNodesToVisit.ElementAt(indexx);
            }
            else
            {
                curr = pathNodesToVisit.ElementAt(0);
            }
```

A few words : pathNodesToVisit are all the nods which I want to visit(Dijkstra algorithm) , in the code above I remove the curr node from the list and the new curr node is a node which had the Costs and Calea changed.

Comment: It's hard to be certain just from the code you've posted, but it seems that you're setting `curr.Neighbors.ElementAt(i).Calea` to the **same object** for all values of `i`, so when you add values you're adding them to the same object each time. Perhaps you need a  _clone_ of `curr.Calea`?

Comment: Ah no , I set curr to different node each time , I will add that  sample code also

Comment: @paparazzo What?

Comment: @Amy Go two parse right and sometimes.

Comment: Ok here it is I hope is more clear now

Comment: @DStanley I added a little more code let me know if it's still unclear

Comment: the private `calea` member will always remain null, you should assign the new instance to `calea` in the getter and then return `calea`, not return the anonymous instance.

Comment: @dlatikay First I did like you said , didn't worked

Comment: but closer to a working solution for sure.

Comment: @dlatikay I don't know cause I have values in calea , but they are stacking up for exemple , if a node A has two neighboors b and c , and c has a neighboor d then d will have  var Calea as {A , C , B ,D} which is not correct , that's what I mean by stacking up

Comment: Isn't that the `Minimum cost flow` algorithm ?

Comment: @Franck Well I am trying to get the optimal solution for a path between 2 given nodes and I want to go in each node and calculate each path cost for each neighbour , as far as I know it is Dijkstra  but I am not using adjacency matrix

Comment: @GabrielCostin Might worth looking into google developper. Reading your question i see the exact same problem i did fix using the [Min cost flow](https://developers.google.com/optimization/flow/mincostflow) from google developper. Editing value was so easy as the format is a simple array.

Comment: @Franck Well thank you that algorithm is interesting I will look into it , and I have got the answer to my questions thanks to Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you mean by "stacking up," but:

```
     public LinkedList<GraphNode<string>> Calea
    {
        get
        {

            if (calea == null) return new LinkedList<GraphNode<string>>();

            return calea;

        }
```

... creates a new list **every time the property is read**, not just the first time. `calea` will always be `null` with this approach.

Try

```
get 
{
    if (null == calea)
       calea = new LinkedList<GraphNode<string>>();

    return calea;
}
```

**Update**

The line

```
curr.Neighbors.ElementAt(i).Calea = curr.Calea;
```

Does not make a copy of the list. It copies a *reference* to the list. Any changes made to any node's `calea` afterward will affect every node, not just the one you're after.

Try

```
curr.Neighbors.ElementAt(i).Calea = new LinkedList<GraphNode<string>>(curr.Calea);
```

Though, you should make sure `.Neighbors` actually has an element `i` before doing this, among other things.

Note: In the case of an uninitialized node, this will actually create two lists - once when Calea is read (LH of the expression, which calls your `.get`), and another on the right.

There are many ways to copy a collection. I suggest googling `c# deep copy LinkedList<T>`.

Comment: Still not working , same situation and by stacking up I am meaning that after n nodes visited , Calea var it's like {node 1,node 2,node 3,node 4,...,node n} which of course is not correct , because not all nodes have same neighbours  for exemple , if a node A has two neighboors b and c , and c has a neighboor d then d will have var Calea as {A , C , B ,D}

Comment: @GabrielCostin see my update above. Also, you might want to google "C# auto-implemented properties." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties

Comment: So then how can I have a list Calea(path) for each Node? I am using same strategy for Neighbours , which actually works..

Comment: @GabrielCostin I can't guess why this works in another circumstance. The code provided doesn't duplicate the list. See my second update. Or search google for 'How to deep copy a LinkedList c#'. :/

Comment: Actually that works , thank you very much , but could you explain why it is working? for me is almost the same thing , the only difference I can see is that when I set Calea for a neighbour I create a new LinkedList with the items of an already created LinkedList

Comment: @GabrielCostin In your posted implementation, you're only ever creating *one list*, no matter how many `GraphNode`s you create. When you, instead, pass the list as an argument to `LinkedList`'s constructor, you are creating a new `LinkedList`. The list elements are still stored by reference, but the list itself is a different entity. Your first version was similar to using a `static` member, while the modified version allows each `GraphNode` to have it's own list, with its own set of elements. References are pointers with some syntactic sugar - just like C++ references.

Comment: .Neighbors always have an element i cause i is iterated by the number of neighbors of the current node

Comment: @GabrielCostin alrighty. I missed that part. Shrug.

Comment: Was my bad because I didn't included that part in the sample code, I always try to make code sample contains as less code as possible cause no one would read 2 pages of code just to help a dumb. And about the .Neighbors variable , I have to admit that I am not doing same method to instantiate which is that I have a graph which contains a method to add a vertex between 2 nodes for exemple from.Neighboor.Add(to) but why this list isn't the same?Just cause I use Add method from List?

Comment: @GabrielCostin I would *guess* that it's due to the way you're using the other structure. Without the code, I can't say for sure. It may still have the same bug, but it's just not presenting any symptoms. Also, posting two pages of code is just fine and it really helps. We prefer a minimal, complete and verifiable example for things like this. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @GabrielCostin And this isn't a dumb question. That's what this site is for, despite what the downvote police would have you believe.

Comment: Well same way , private GNodeList<T> neighbors=null;,  protected GNodeList<T> Neighbors
            {
                get
                {
                    return neighbors;
                }
                set
                {
                    neighbors = value;
                }
            }

Comment: @GabrielCostin `set { neighbors = value; }` assigns the list *reference* to `self.neighbors` - *it does not copy the contents of the list*. So, no idea. Again, I can't really debug your code based on one line in the comments section.